# Where shall I ask questions when the site is "Commitment" phase?

Tags: discussion, questions, area-51

My current algorithm of asking questions on  StackExchange when I don't know if there is an appropriate site is the following:

1. Try searching is there is already beta or graduated SE site for the topic. If there is, ask there;
2. If not found, try searching on Area51. If the proposal is found, add (unless duplicate) the question there as an example question, expecting that the question may finally migrate to beta someday;
3. If there are no matching proposals (existing or abandoned), create a proposal, then add my question as the first example question.

[4. If the algorithm fails, like now, ask on Meta where to ask].

In any case, I don't like my curiosity being stopped by obstacles without a change being fulfilled.

But the "commitment" phase seems to be a trap: the gathering examples "vent" is closed, but beta "vent" is not yet opened? But where to ask then?

Comment: Previous post of the questoin on discuss.area51.SE: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/19533/where-shall-i-ask-questions-when-the-site-is-commitment-phase

Answer (score 4):

If you are actually looking for an answer to your question, the proces already breaks down at step 2.

The sample questions that are collected during the proposal phase in area51 are not migrated to the site's beta (if it ever makes it that far).
The reason for this is that the sample questions are no more than headlines and they miss the actual meat that would make them a high quality answerable question.

So, if you want an answer, either you look for an existing site that can accept your question, or you write the question down to post it to a proposed site when it goes into the beta phase.

Comment: The sample questions on Area51 remain accessible after the site going beta (or maybe further), so I they are already "written" (and in the proper place, as opposed to unsearchable unpublished easy-to-lose private files).

Comment: @Vi.: The headlines of the questions may remain available, but they are no better than that. Someone will have to take those headlines and turn them into proper questions. To do that, you need to know what was in the mind of the proposer. In that sense, they are just as good as a question in unpublished private files.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real place to ask them. What i do in this case is keep a document with a list of questions that i'm waiting to ask.

Comment: How do I make this document 1. searchable by others (including ones who can answer), 2. deduplicated across other users who may have similar question? The "Sample question" seems to be the right place for this.

Comment: You could make it searchable by posting it online, i suppose.